# Implementing an HTTP Server - do I have to respond to all requests?

Tags: http

If I am making an HTTP server, can I choose to ignore requests I don't want to respond to and let them time out?

I'm just wondering whether I am in any sense better off not responding to requests from potentially malicious sources than responding to them with data I'd rather not serve up, or responding with some `403 Forbidden` or similar response that lets them know I exist.

Comment: Did you consider using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) ? It probably would be simpler for you (and handles all of HTTP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `403` should suffice. But I wouldn't let it just time out. If someone is trying to be cheeky, a time out will be more informative than a `Service Unavailable 503`.

I answered a relevant question a while back, read the question/answer, it's about a specific use case, but it does mention cases where you don't want to return an HTTP status code because it gives too much info.

[RFC - 404 or 400 for relation of entity not found in PUT request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773495/2803660)

Also have a look at this [list of HTTP Status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes), you can always use something like `Too Many Requests 429`, a `Not Acceptable 406` or even something like `I'm a teapot 418` ;)

Comment: How can a time out and no response at all be more informative than any response? Surely if you get any response, it tells you something is there, but if you get no response... you can't deduce anything, can you?

Comment: If you try to hit an endpoint that doesn't exist it'll return with `Cant reach server`, if you try to reach an unimplemented route you'll get a `404 Not Found` - Depending on how you're setting up your API.
If you just allow it to timeout, it would tell you that something is processing, or that something isn't quite right. So If I'm just trying to keep your server busy that's one way for me to know that I'm actually hitting something that exists.
It's my opinion anyway.

Comment: It's also to your benefit to early out and end the request as soon as possible in order to conserve resources. Depending on your stack, you might slow down other requests as you handle more and more load.